# Special Alert Dialog in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create an alert dialog as shown below.

[image: Special Dialog seen on all Google Products]

I don't know if there is any special name for this. I want to create this kind of Alert Dialog for my android application. Can Someone help me in achieving this?

EDIT: (after Dmytro Batyuk's Clarification)
I want to create this kind of popup window to create a tutorial walk-through for my android application. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about **PopupWindow** ?

Updated:
 you need to look at PopupWindow implementation and if it has such style - feel free to use. Otherwise you need to implement your own style.
Also you can google different existing implementation if you think it's hard for you and modify them